# Looking for comprehensive English-German dictionar(y/ies) in a database format

Tags: translation, german-to-english, dictionary

I'm currently researching per-word language translation (as opposed to the per-sentence/in-context translation provided by eg Google Translate), and as a part of this I'm looking for a comprehensive English-language (as in, I speak English) German dictionary which will map German words against one or more (preferably several) categorical/descriptive English counterparts.

I'm also looking for something with a basic English description of the grammatical inflection of the German words I am looking at, so I can correctly infer the structure of the sentence(s) I am reading.

I'm not sure what format such a database would use, but it would need to be something easy to query programmatically (my sole intention). *(As such, the only way I would be looking at software which included such a database would be as a reverse-engineering challenge (!) :P)*

I've done a bit of cursory poking around - particularly in the open-source sector - but the offerings I've turned up have fallen apart rather horribly and simply returned no results for lookups of words like "wirst", "mich" or "isst" - and some did provide basic grammatical "grounding", but none felt adequate. But then, I make no claims that I have any idea what's really out there, or where/how to start looking for it.

So, what are my options?

My intentions are strictly for personal, educational use, so open-source is not a critical requirement - "free for non-commercial use" or "free for educational purposes" works just as well for me.

I also don't mind aggregating more than one database or data-source together - I certainly do not require a singular resource to provide all the features I am looking for. I have no upper limit on how many databases I combine.

Lastly, an online service which provided live word translation would be acceptable, if it provided a free account option which would put up with around a hundred queries a day.

Comment: Was die Ansprüche ans grammatische sind habe ich nicht verstanden - bist Du steak/xsteak begegnet? Ist Open Source (nicht in den Ubuntu-Repos).

Comment: @userunknown: Ooh, `steak` looks very useful, and was easy to install - thanks! Regarding grammar, I am looking for a database that operates like a combination of [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/deen/grammatisch), [translategerman.info](http://www.translategerman.info/en/dictionary-german-english/grammatisch) and [bab.la](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/german-english/grammatische), but without an internet connection. `steak` seems to be a good start.

Comment: Did you think of Wikipedia and Wiktionaries?

Comment: Wiktionary looks very very much exactly like what I'm looking for - thanks!! And since it's a wiki, [the whole thing **can** be downloaded](http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/) for offline manipulation (*but beware, you'd be getting SQL'd MediaWiki markup, which you would need to do a lot of postprocessing on to find helpful*). As of Sep 2014, this is 485MB, so not an unmanageably large size.

Comment: @i336_ Ok, so I make an answer out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Steak/XSteak sind 2 Programme, eines für die Kommandozeile, eines graphisch, die beide auf die gleiche Datenbasis zugreifen. 
Sie stehen unter einer Open-Source-Lizenz und sind bei [FreeCode (vormals Freshmeat)](http://freecode.com/projects/xsteak) zu finden.